# Multiple combinations of parameters give the same accuracy in cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, svm, opencv3.0, cross-validation

I'm working on image classification using Bag Of Visual Words, SIFT and SVM with RBF kernel.
I'm doing some cross-validation tuning the following parameters: k (dictionary size); c, gamma (kernel values).

I've tried 1100 different (k, c, gamma) combinations but several of them obtained the best accuracy value (which is around 95,3%).
How can I choose the combination that guarantees me the better generalization?
(The one that'll give me the best result on the test set)

The only data I have are the 1100 values of accuracy relative to each combination.

EDIT
I'm sorry I forgot to say that I have 6 classes, I know ROC can be extended to multiclass problems but I'm looking for something else, if exists.

My validation set has 4 images for each class so the accuracy is just: 
(number of correctly classified images)/(24)

Comment: How are you measuring accuracy?

Comment: Accuracy is not a good measure of performance. Something like ROC is better. And you can never "guarantee" which one will give you the best result on new data. Also, 1100 different combinations is quite high - I'd suggest going with a much lower number so that your training and evaluation time decreases significantly.